# How do I configure Araxis Merge for use with Git?

Tags: git-merge, git-config

I understand that Araxis Merge is now a "fully supported" `mergetool` for Git, so that much of what I can find about configuring Git to use it is now out of date. In particular, Araxis Merge should work "out of the box" simply by executing

```
git config --global merge.tool araxis
```

provided `araxis` is on my PATH.

However, for a several reasons, amending my PATH is not an option, so I need to be able to specify the correct `path` or `cmd` in `.gitconfig`.

How should I configure Git (on OS X) so that it finds Araxis Merge? Simply following the example of other tools like `kdiff3` and `p4merge` with

```
git config --global mergetool.araxis.path /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/MacOS/Araxis Merge
```

doesn't work; nor does (guessing) with

```
git config --global mergetool.araxis.path /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/araxisgitmerge
git config --global difftool.araxis.path /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/araxisgitdiff
```

How should I configure my `araxis.path`? Are there additional Git settings that should be used with Araxis Merge?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Git now uses the Araxis `compare` utility directly, rather than `araxisgitdiff` and `araxisgitmerge`, so all that's needed is to set the `path` to

```
/Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
```

for example, by executing

```
git config --global mergetool.araxis.path '/Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare'
```

or by directly editing `~/.gitconfig` to contain

```
[mergetool "araxis"]
     path = /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
```

Comment: You can also force it to open in full screen by adding `/max` param at the end, like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Araxis\Araxis Merge\Compare.exe /max`. Works on Windows

Comment: @MladenJanjetović: Doesn't work. Adding `-max` to `path` fails.

Comment: @  raxacoricofallapatorius did you try `/max`? Not `-max`. I am using this in tortoiseSvn, too

Comment: @MladenJanjetović: Both. I'm on OS X, so `-max` works from the command line.

Comment: @ raxacoricofallapatorius - On windows works fine. I see that there is param available on iOS documentation for araxis console, but don't have apple to try: http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-os-x/command-line.en

Comment: @MladenJanjetović: I'm not sure why it doesn't work here. The `-max` option does work at the command line. Perhaps you mean `cmd = ...`, sith suitable additional arguments (whatever those are) to capture the commits?

Answer (score 6):

Hard to make sense of the thread here, so I'm pasting below the exact .gitconfig that worked for me:

```
[diff]
tool = araxis

[merge]
tool = araxis

[mergetool "araxis"]
        path = /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
```

Comment: for googlers...

1) need use "" after `path =`.
`path = "/Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare"`

2) I added all code to `~/.gitconfig`, local file gitconfig not works, I don't know why...

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are running git version 1.6.4 or above. Copy these utilities from the Utilities folder in the Araxis Merge install image to `/usr/local/bin`.

```
araxisgitmerge
araxisopendiff
compare
compare2
```

Then edit `~/.gitconfig` and add these lines:

```
[diff]
    tool = araxis
[merge]
    tool = araxis
```

The next time you type `git mergetool` it should launch the Araxis Merge graphical tool.

This information was taken from the official Araxis documentation [here](http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/scm_integration.html#Git).

Answer (score 1):

@raxacoricofallapatorius great answer! But you need to run that command line with quotes (due to the space in Araxis Merge. Without quotes produced a truncated path of "/Applications/Araxis" which didn't work obviously, but adding quotes and re-running that command fixed my issues. Thanks!

Fix:

```
git config --global mergetool.araxis.path "/Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare"
```

Comment: Thanks. That should be a comment on the answer above, now fixed, or  a suggested edit, rather than new answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SourceTree (I'm using v3.0.8) it's very easy to configure Araxis merge as the external diff tool:

For using Araxis Merge to *view* file differences:

- Install Araxis Merge
- In SourceTree: Tools > Options > Diff > External Diff Tool > select AraxisMerge from dropdown > OK

(No need to define the Arguments, no need to restart SourceTree)

Example use:

- Right-click an uncommitted file that you want to compare > select 'External Diff' (or select file then `CTRL-D`) - this will compare the differences between your latest changes and your local repo.