# Mac OsX: Git don't open Araxis on git mergetool command

Tags: git, git-merge, mergetool, araxis

When I try to do a merge from git I call `git mergetool`, but it doesn't open Araxis for merging.

This is my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
  tool = araxis

[merge]
  tool = araxis
```

And this is the result:

```
$ git mergetool
Merging:
src/main/webapp/css/style.css

Normal merge conflict for 'src/main/webapp/css/style.css':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (araxis):
src/main/webapp/css/style.css seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] n
merge of src/main/webapp/css/style.css failed
```

What could I have forgotten?

Comment: This other post has the answer you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593817/how-do-i-configure-araxis-merge-for-use-with-git