# configuring araxis merge with git version 2.5.1.windows.1

Tags: git, araxis-merge

I am trying to configure araxis merge with git and tried the thread below:

[How do I configure Araxis Merge for use with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593817/how-do-i-configure-araxis-merge-for-use-with-git)

however it did not work for me. here's how my .git config looks like:

```
[user]
    email = myemail@email.com
    name = MyName
[mergetool "araxis"]
    path = "C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe"
[difftool "araxis"]
    path = "C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe"
```

but when I try, `$ git difftool` I get:

```
This message is displayed because diff.tool is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
kompare emerge vimdiff
```

Can someone spot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your config:

```
[diff]
tool = araxis
```