# How do I get araxis merge to work as a git difftool

Tags: git, git-difftool, araxis-merge

I've been trying to setup araxis as git difftool, but it never works.

I looked at this thread but it is incomplete:

[How do I configure Araxis Merge for use with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593817/how-do-i-configure-araxis-merge-for-use-with-git)

here is part of my global config.

```
[difftool "araxis"]
    path = "C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe"
[diff]
    tool = araxis
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\gmmo\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

but when I have some unstaged changes and issue "git difftool" I get this:

[image]

If anyone has some hints, I greatly appreciate!

thx!

Comment: On Win7 with cygwin, put this in git config difftool:
cmd = C:/INSTALL_DIR/compare.exe \"$(cygpath -wa $LOCAL)\" \"$(cygpath -wa $REMOTE)\"

Comment: I had a the same problem, for me this worked    `[difftool "araxis"]
    cmd = c:/Tools/Araxis/Araxis\\ Merge/Merge.exe $(cygpath -wa $LOCAL) $(cygpath -wa $REMOTE)`  The direction of the / do matter, they don't have to be dos / but you may like me have to escape the space with \\  , I'm also using cygwin so that will likely alter your usage if you are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally bad and wrong definition in [difftool]

I don't have Git+Araxis, but Araxis docs recommends in "Integrating with Source Control, Configuration Management and Other Applications" chapter's topic [Git for Windows (msysGit)](http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/integrating-with-other-applications.en#Git)

```
[diff]
tool = araxis
[difftool "araxis"]
path = C:\\Program Files\\Araxis\\Araxis Merge\\compare.exe
```

note:

- filename of differ
- **double backlsashes** for separating path-elements

Comment: Sorry this just doesn't work!, so if you don't have Araxis, then I don't think you can answer this question accurately..

Comment: Upvoted for the link to the Araxis Merge docs, which have the git config to use and the explaination about why.  It's been a few years and for the record though, for the `path` I just use forward slashes (`C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/compare.exe`) and it works just fine for me.